# free jqGrid, column chooser popup UI not appearing correctly

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm using free jqgrid and implemented column chooser to show hide columns, the functionality is working as expected but the popup that shows up doesn't have a proper rendering of UI.

I tried searching a lot and went through the documentation of free jqgrid but I don't know what am I doing wrong.

I was able to reproduce the error in demo in below url.

If any one has faced similar issue please help. Note I am using bootstrap theme.

```
$("#sampleGrid").navButtonAdd('#sampleGridPager',{
        caption: "",
        title: "Choose Columns",
        buttonicon: "fa fa-table",
        onClickButton: function () {
           $("#sampleGrid").jqGrid('columnChooser');
        }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1vk5ku2y/2/

Comment: the demo need to add jQuery UI CSS because it needs `columnChooser`. You should add some jQuery UI theme, which corresponds Bootsrap CSS theme. After that one get already good results: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/1vk5ku2y/4/. You need add just minor CSS fixes to have the final solution.

Comment: this worked thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome! I posted the same information as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to add jQuery UI CSS to the demo because it's required for `columnChooser`. You should add some jQuery UI theme, which corresponds Bootsrap CSS theme. For example

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css
```

After that one get already much better results https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/1vk5ku2y/4/. You need to add minor CSS fixes to have the final solution.